# Is there a version of postActionEvent for KeyEvent (specifically for a JTextArea)?

Tags: java, swing, action, jtextarea, keyevent

I'm writing a program that contains multiple JTextFields and 2 JTextAreas within an input panel.  I have a submit button on the bottom.  I have it set up so when a user types something into each field (including the JTextAreas) and hits the Enter key, it updates a text file, and when they press the submit button it updates the file then outputs a new version of it in the local directory.

If the user presses Enter in any of the fields, it validates their input, however, I want to re-validate all fields when they press the submit button.  Each field (again, JTextAreas included) has it's own validation check within its ActionListener or KeyListener (for the JTextAreas).  It's easy enough to use postActionEvent() for the JTextFields, but **is there a similar method for the JTextAreas to force fire a KeyEvent?**  I don't want to duplicate code and consume memory by re-writing the validation for those 2 Components inside the ActionEvent for the JButton.

Unfortunately, I can't provide a sample because I'm writing the program on a classified machine (PC).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simulate <kbd>ENTER</kbd> being pressed using [`Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class `keyPress(..)` and `keyRelease(..)` methods. You would of course have to iterate through all `JTextAreas` on the component and call `requestFocusInWindow(..)` followed by the simulated keypress (`Exception` handling omitted):

```
Robot robot = new Robot();//throws AWTException

...

Component[] components=getContentPane().getComponents();  

for(int i=0;i<components.length;i++)  
{
    if(components[i] instanceof JTextArea) { 
         components[i].requestFocusInWindow();
         simulateEnter();
     }
}

public static void simulateEnter() {
     robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
     robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
}
```

Comment: +1 again for the info, but again have a closer look at what Java Docs has to say regarding `requestFocus()` method in this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#requestFocusInWindow(boolean)). In favour of `requestFocusInWindow()` **The focus behavior of this method can be implemented uniformly across platforms, and thus developers are strongly encouraged to use this method over requestFocus when possible. Code which relies on requestFocus may exhibit different focus behavior on different platforms**

Comment: @GagandeepBali +1 thank you for the very useful information. Edit has been made

Comment: Thank you for pointing me at the Robot class.  This will help put out a functioning version of my product.  Thank you for taking the time to help me!

Answer (score 4):

Why trying to post a `KeyEvent` to trigger the validation when you can simply call your `validate` method, e.g. in pseudo-code

```
myTextArea.getDocument().addDocumentListener(){
  //in each of the method you call validate

}

private function validate( ){
  //do your validation
}

private function submitButtonFunction(){
  validate();
}
```

Also note that the recommended way is to use a `DocumentListener` if you want to react on input in a `JTextComponent`. For example your `KeyListener` will not be triggered after a drag-and-drop. Depending on the implementation of your `KeyListener`, it might also fail when you use copy-paste.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on DocumentListener, copy-paste is a big part of what they enter into the JTextArea. I didn't put it across clearly enough though, and that's my fault.  There is no validation method, just built in code to validate each field within their own EventListener.  Each field requires too different criteria to validate collectively, or have a generic validation method.  That's why I need to fire the KeyEvent (or DocumentListener if I go that route).  Thank you for taking the time to help though.  I think (at least temporarily) the Robot class is my best option.